# how to wrap cURL so you can use your command line editor to work with Cloudant Query?

Tags: bash, cloudant

I'm looking to create a shell script that wraps common cURL operations for [Cloudant Query](https://docs.cloudant.com/guides/cloudant-query.html).

The shell script should allow me to:

- create a query using json embedded in the script
- delete a query by providing the design doc name, query type and query name
- execute a query (find) using json embedded in the script
- list queries on a database

The script should NOT prompt you for your cloudant username and password each time you use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script allows me to stay in the vim editor and iteratively edit my JSON and execute it:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

USERNAME=snowch
DBNAME=stackoverflow
FIND_JSON='{
    "selector": {
        "subject": {"$eq": "sample topic"}
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "subject"],
    "sort": [{"subject": "asc"}],
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": 0
  }'

CREATE_JSON='
  {
      "index": {
          "fields": ["subject"]
      },
      "name" : "subject-index",
      "type" : "json"
  }'

JSON_PP='python -m json.tool' # By default use pythons json formatter
#JSON_PP="jq '.'"             # Uncomment this to use the jq json formatter

SCRIPT=$(basename $0)

if [[ ! $1 =~ (create)|(list)|(delete)|(find)  ]]; then
  echo "Usage: ./$SCRIPT create|list|delete|find"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -e ~/.netrc ]]; then
  echo "Could not find your ~/.netrc file containing your Cloudant login credentials.  For example:"
  echo ""
  echo "machine <<username>>.cloudant.com login <<username>> password <<password>>"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $1 == 'find' ]]; 
then
  curl -n -X POST https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DBNAME/_find -d "$FIND_JSON"
fi

if [[ $1 == 'create' ]]; 
then
  curl -n -X POST https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DBNAME/_index -d "$CREATE_JSON"
fi

if [[ $1 == 'list' ]]; 
then
  CMD="curl -n -s -X GET https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DBNAME/_index | $JSON_PP"
  eval "$CMD"
fi

if [[ $1 == 'delete' ]]; 
then
  if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ./$SCRIPT delete design_doc/type/name"
    exit 1
  fi
  curl -n -s -X DELETE https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DBNAME/_index/$2
fi
```

If I save the script as `util.sh` my workflow using vim becomes something like:

- $ vim util.sh
- edit create json
- CTRL-Z to background vim
- create the query: `$ ./util.sh create`
- verify it: `$ ./util.sh list`
- execute it: `$ ./util.sh find`
- if changes are required:

  - get the design doc name (ddoc) from `$ ./util.sh list`
  - delete the query `$ ./util.sh delete <<designdoc_name>>/json/subject-index`
  - bring vim back to the foreground `fg`
  - edit the json
  - repeat the previous steps from CTRL-Z to background vim

Note that the script requires python to pretty print the json returned by Cloudant.  You can change this to jq or your preferred tool.